# document.getElementById returns null when working with iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, getelementbyid

My html page has the following 2 scripts:

1.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        document.write("<iframe id=\"frame\" src=\"http://mywebsite.com/" + "\"scrolling=\"yes\" width=\"850\" height=\"575\" frameborder=0></iframe>");
    </script>
```

2.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var myframe = document.getElementById("frame");
    if (myframe) {

        var myframe_window = document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow;
        if (myframe_window) {
            myframe_window.confirm = window.confirm;
        }
    }

</script>
```

I'm trying to override a methiod in iFrame, but cannot get its id.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the iFrame from the same domain as the parent document?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to get the element before it is actually created? At what point are you calling the second block of code?

Comment: Most likely a same-origin policy problem

Comment: iFrame is in different domain and I'm trying to override its method.

Comment: You can't, due to the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: Actually, I changed the order of the code and able to get the id. I'm not able to get the method though

Comment: I run accroos some posts here regarding my issue and seems like it is doable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929996/is-it-possible-to-override-javascript-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-if-so-how so tried to do kind of the same